# TensorFlowのチュートリアル「Logging and Monitoring Basics with tf.contrib.learn」のエラー

Tags: tensorflow

現在、TensorFlowのチュートリアルの「[Logging and Monitoring Basics with tf.contrib.learn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/monitors/index.html)」を行っています。

チュートリアルのサンプルコードのうち、`load_csv`はdeprecatedの為、 `load_csv_with_header`に変更した下記を実行したところ、エラーが発生しました。

## 実行したコード

```
#  Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.

"""Model training for Iris data set using Validation Monitor."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
# training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
#                                                        target_dtype=np.int)
# test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TEST,
#                                                    target_dtype=np.int)

training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32, target_column=-1)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                                   target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32, target_column=-1)



validation_metrics = {"accuracy": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
                      "precision": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
                      "recall": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall}
validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
    test_set.data,
    test_set.target,
    every_n_steps=50,
    metrics=validation_metrics,
    early_stopping_metric="loss",
    early_stopping_metric_minimize=True,
    early_stopping_rounds=200)

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=3,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model",
                                            config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
                                                save_checkpoints_secs=1))

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=2000,
               monitors=[validation_monitor])

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,
                                     y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]
print("Accuracy: {0:f}".format(accuracy_score))

# Classify two new flower samples.
new_samples = np.array(
    [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]], dtype=float)
y = list(classifier.predict(new_samples, as_iterable=True))
print("Predictions: {}".format(str(y)))
```

## 表示されたエラー

```
ValueError: Metrics passed provide only name, no prediction, but predictions are dict. Metrics: {'recall': <function streaming_recall at 0x10c8dede8>, 'precision': <function streaming_precision at 0x10c8dec80>, 'accuracy': <tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.metric_spec.MetricSpec object at 0x10fc8b110>}, Targets: Tensor("output:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64).
```

チュートリアル内「Customizing the Evaluation Metrics」で`validation_monitor`を変更したところエラーが発生するようになったため、その辺りに原因があるかと思いますが、解決策が分かりませんでした。

対応策をご存知の方、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validation_metricsを以下のように定義することで動作しました。

```
    validation_metrics = {
    "accuracy":
        tf.contrib.learn.metric_spec.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.prediction_key.PredictionKey.
            CLASSES),
    "precision":
        tf.contrib.learn.metric_spec.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.prediction_key.PredictionKey.
            CLASSES),
    "recall":
        tf.contrib.learn.metric_spec.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.prediction_key.PredictionKey.
            CLASSES)
}
```

上記は
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/monitors/
にて説明されている内容そのままになります。

ご提示のコードの様な省略記法があるのかもしれませんがそのあたり詳しくないものでとりあえずの回答とさせていただきます。